# JOIN on multiple tables giving duplicate records - MySql

Tags: mysql, join

Here is list of my tables and necessary columns

**users u** .

```
screen_name,
country,
status
```

**twitter_users_relationship tf**. This table have multiple `target_screen_name` for each `screen_name`.

```
screen_name,
target_screen_name,
target_country,
follow_status
```

**user_twitter_action_map ta**

```
screen_name,
action_name,
action_status
```

**user_targeted_countries utc** .This table have multiple countries for each `screen_name`

```
screen_name,
country_name
```

I want to get all `target_screen_name` from `twitter_users_relationship` that have matched `target_country` with `u.country` or `utc.country_name`

My query so far

```
SELECT u.screen_name,
       u.country,
       tf.target_screen_name,
       tf.target_country,
       ta.action_name,
       ta.action_status,
       utc.country_name

FROM users u
 LEFT JOIN twitter_users_relationship tf
   ON u.screen_name=tf.screen_name
 LEFT JOIN user_twitter_action_map ta
   ON u.screen_name=ta.screen_name
   AND ta.action_name='follow'
   AND ta.action_status='active'
 LEFT JOIN user_targeted_countries utc
   ON u.screen_name= utc.screen_name
WHERE u.status = 'active'
  AND tf.follow_status = 'pending'
  AND tf.target_country != ''
  AND tf.target_country IS NOT NULL
  AND ( utc.country_name=tf.target_country OR u.country=tf.target_country)
  AND u.screen_name = 'my_screen_name';
```

But this query giving me duplicate record for each entry of countries in `user_targeted_countries`. If there are 3 counties in `user_targeted_countries` the it will return 3 duplicate records.

Please let me know what `JOIN` I need to use with `user_targeted_countries` to get desired results.

`u.country` can be different than countries in `utc.country_name`

**UPDATE** -
If I removes `OR u.country=tf.target_country` from the `WHERE` clause then I get all the matched target_screen_name without duplicate. But I am not sure how to get all those records also that matches with `u.country=tf.target_country` ?

Comment: JOIN's are known the give duplicated results if one-to-many or many-to-many relationships are used within a JOIN... normally DISTINCT will help to remove duplicates.

Comment: Is it normal or I need more practice to use `JOIN` properly ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland Distinct won't work here as the `country_name` column is probably different ..

Comment: true i've missed that in the question @sagi

Comment: If I removes  `OR u.country=tf.target_country` from the `WHERE` clause then I get the all the matched `target_screen_name` without duplicate. But I am not sure how to get all those records also that matches with `u.country=tf.target_country` ?

A `UNION` can help ?

Comment: "But this query giving me duplicate record for each entry of countries in user_targeted_countries. If there are 3 counties in user_targeted_countries the it will return 3 duplicate records."  Sample data results using https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ added to your question would help.  But based on the above, it's operating correctly.  Information will be duplicated for each record in countries that match the screen name.  in addition the right side tables in a left join must have the criteria added to the join or the join will behave like an inner join..

Comment: @xQbert - Updating my Question. BTW `u.screen_name` is PK in `users` table. Other tables have Auto Increment columns which are not having any relations among tables

Comment: Ok.  then you have 1:M relationships which, if you add the auto increment columns to your select, will show you why you have multiple records and which table is giving you more than you expect.  Then you can manage the by adding criteria to the join I suspect part of the problem is the OR statement `( utc.country_name=tf.target_country OR u.country=tf.target_country)`  if a screen name could have multiple utc.countries, then you would get back more than 1 record.

Comment: Yea. utc.countries giving duplicates record . I will follow the steps you mention to see which table giving unexpected records

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the business logic required ..

First, regardless to the question, your query is wrong(Either the `LEFT JOIN` or the conditions) . When using `LEFT JOIN` , conditions on the right table should **only** be specified in the `ON` clause, which means you need to move all the conditions on `tf.` and `utc.` to the `ON` clause.

Secondly, you can use a `GROUP BY` clause and choose one of the `utc.country_name` (different answers will be if you want a specific one, if it doesn't matter, use `MAX()` on this column).

Comment: Ok. Will try by putting condition with `ON`.
But I will not prefer to use `GROUP BY` because I may want records in different orders and may remove `u.screen_name='my_screen_name'` condition.